# ¿Cómo añado un salto de línea con thymeleaf dentro de una misma celda o elemento?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Necesito hacer un salto de línea **dentro** de una misma celda o `<td>` por cada elemento de una `List`.
El problema es que no puedo iterar con `th:each` sobre el `<td>` porque la celda se cierra así misma en cada iteración y no se si se puede hacer algo como esto con un `<br>` dentro del `th:text`:

```
<th:block th:each="..." th:text="| ... <br />|" />
```

Este es el código:

```
<th:block th:if="${proyectoCreado.puestos.size != 0}">
    <td>
        <th:block 
            th:each="puesto : ${proyectoCreado.puestos}" 
            th:text="|· ${puesto.nombre}|"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <th:block th:each="puesto : ${proyectoCreado.puestos}">
            <th:block
                th:if="${puesto.ocupante?.nombre != null}" 
                th:text="|· ${puesto.ocupante.nombre}|" />
            <th:block th:unless="${puesto.ocupante?.nombre != null}">
                Libre
            </th:block>
        </th:block>
    </td>
</th:block>
```

Y el objetivo es que por cada nombre de puesto (primera celda), se haga una lista de Nombres **en la misma celda** y que por cada ocupante de esos puestos (1 por puesto), si lo hay, lo mismo, con sus respectivos nombres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurrió que la solución podría pasar por añadir una lista a la celda, que al final me fuerza ese salto de línea que necesitaba dentro de la misma celda:

```
<th:block th:if="${proyectoCreado.puestos.size != 0}">
    <td>
        <ul th:each="puesto : ${proyectoCreado.puestos}">
            <li th:text="${puesto.nombre}" />
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul th:each="puesto : ${proyectoCreado.puestos}">
            <li th:if="${puesto.ocupante?.nombre != null}" 
                th:text="${puesto.ocupante.nombre}" />
            <li th:unless="${puesto.ocupante?.nombre != null}">
                Libre
            <li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</th:block>
```